# How do you find and remove a Mongoose subdocument within an array by its id?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following mongoose schema:

```
{
    name: String,
    subArray: [
        {
            subName: String,
            subNumber: Number
        }
    ]
}
```

I've added objects to the subArray, which get automatically assigned an `"_id"`. In Node.js, how do I find an object by `"_id"` within the subArray and remove it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can se mongoose [`findOneAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) along with `$pull` operator. So something like following would work (untested):

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate( {'subArray._id' : '55a19992474e7ded6b4ae2b0'} ,
  {
    $pull: { subArray: { _id: '55a19992474e7ded6b4ae2b0' }}
  }
  {new: true},
  function(err, doc){
     console.log(err,doc)
})
```

Comment: how to know if subdocument is deleted or not? because when I try to delete a non-existing subdocument it did not give me any error. So how to check such scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

A small correction for the above code sefgment

```
ProductContact.findOneAndUpdate({'productRoles._id':req.params.product_role_id}, 
{
  $pull: { productRoles: {_id:req.params.product_role_id }}
},{new:true}, 
function(err, productcontact) {
  if(err)
    res.send(err);res.json({message: 'Role successfully deleted.'});
})
```